# mysqli_connect() not working with PHP and Tomcat

Tags: php, mysql, tomcat

I've just got PHP working on Tomcat and when I try and call MySQL using mysqli_connect() I get this error:

java.lang.RuntimeException: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in C:\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\ROOT\php.php on line 1

I've added php_mysqli.dll to C:\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\cgi\amd64-windows\ext and uncommented extension = php_mysqli.dll in C:\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\cgi\amd64-windows\conf.d\mysql.ini

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like you have a very old version of PHP and need to upgrade it. Why are you building PHP apps in Tomcat anyway? It's not optimised for it.

Comment: Im running php 5.3.1. Because I only want to run one server. More servers running = more resources getting used

Comment: If you're using Tomcat, why not just access the database in Java?

Comment: I've got a CMS project that I made in PHP and I want to port it across to Tomcat from Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get this working. It looks like using mysql**i**.ini rather than mysql.ini did the magic in my case:
 
- Apache-Tomcat-9.0.10
 
- PHP Version 5.6.38
 
- JavaBridgeTemplate721.war
- MySql 8.0.12
...first had to copy `php5ts.dll` and `php-cgi.exe` to setup the PHP enabled Tomcat project to the:
`\WEB-INF\cgi\x86-windows\`
and then copy `php_mysqli.dll` and setup the `mysqli.ini` to enable the mysqli.